# is there any way to use typeorm with bigquery?

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery, nestjs, typeorm

is there any way to use typeOrm with BigQuery?

i want to connect my nestJs application with BigQuery using typeOrm, i already try lots of ways but didn't get any working solution this is the code suggested by chatGpt but its also not working

`import { BigQueryDriver } from '@google-cloud/bigquery';
import { ConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm';

const connectionOptions: ConnectionOptions = {
type: 'bigquery',
driver: BigQueryDriver,
projectId: 'your-project-id',
keyFilename: 'path/to/keyfile.json',
datasetId: 'your-dataset-id',
};`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think TypeORM will support for Bigquery database connection soon as below already created issue is closed.
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2951

Instead TypeORM maybe you can try this library.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/bigquery